# Reverse engineering what version of ruby and rails a project was developed under

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some background:

I am new to Ruby and Rails and I've been assigned to get an already completed Ruby on Rails project to compile from source.

The project has, as far as I've been able to discover, little to no documentation on how to set it up.  The developers are unavailable for me to contact.

After doing some tutorials and learning the basics I have been trying to get the code to compile and run.  My platform/setup is currently:

- Windows 7
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.13

Although I am attempting to develop with a VirtualBox Ubuntu setup alongside of this because I suspect it will be easier in the long run.

Despite there being no Gemfile for this project I have managed to (I believe) pin down and install all of the necessary gem packages (hopefully compatible versions).  I am now running into this issue:

in `alias_method': undefined method`path' for class `ActionController::UploadedStringIO' (NameError)

As far as my searches have led me to believe this is a bug that can occur when the versions of Ruby and Rails are not correct/incompatible?

Is there a way to "reverse engineer" what version of Ruby and Rails was used to develop this project in the first place from the code alone?  Could this bug be caused by me using 3.2.13 Rails if the original developers were using 1.8.7 Ruby?  It seems to me that if I can emulate their setup closely enough then the source should compile and I can get down to business.

Additionally I am using the default WEBrick server.  Is there a way to determine what the original team used for the web service?  Does it even matter if they used a Apache setup or are these server implementations mostly interchangeable aside from efficiency?

Thank you for your time.  If you have any further advice on how to handle this sort of project I'd love to hear that too.

Comment: The project is okay if you don't have time limit, otherwise a better approach is to return it to boss/client.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no Gemfile, it points to the Rails app being 2.3 or earlier.  As for the Web server, they are interchangeable, but there is really very little chance that they were using Webrick, due to its ability (or lack thereof) to handle many concurrent requests.  Chances are, they were using mongrel, or passenger via Apache or Nginx.

Comment: Good insight.  I created a new setup with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.18 and I've been able overcome my runtime errors.  Thanks!